# Need to implement timeout mechanism for UIRefreshControl.

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uirefreshcontrol

Apple's new UIRefreshControl in iOS 6 is a welcome new feature, but it seems that there is no built-in timeout mechanism.

Here's the scenario why I need it:

Let's say the user pulls the refresh. It goes into the spinning mode, while the code tries to fetch data from the server. The server does not repond and will cause spinning wheel to spin forever. So, there should be a time out mechanism to stop it.

What's the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First setup a timer with the amount of time you need. Ask it to check the following.

You can use the following property to check whether it is still refreshing after some time

> @property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isRefreshing) BOOL refreshing

If it is then you can stop it using

> endRefreshing

Something like :

> -(void)checkAndStop{
>         if(refreshControl.refreshing == YES)
>             // show an alert if you want
>             [refreshControl endRefreshing];
>      }

Comment: Doesn't this have a problem though?  What if you set your timer for 5 seconds.  The user pulls the UIRefreshControl down (starting the timer), and it finishes normally after 2 seconds.  Another 2 seconds later, the user pulls the UIRefreshControl down again.  After 1 second, the original timer hits 5 seconds, and endRefreshing gets called even though the task is not finished executing.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3):

Also consider using dispatch_after, which might be less consumable than creating NSTimer.

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    code to be executed on the main queue after delay
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented using NSTimer to end the refreshing:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(handleDataRefreshFailure:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
let delayInSeconds: UInt64 = 2
let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     if refreshControl.refreshing {
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
     }
   })
```